# Is there a way to create a regex for mac addresses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a list of mac addresses that is stored in a file and I want to collect them all using a regex pattern. It could come in any of the following formats:

3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F

4D:F5:C6:A8:B1:43

4d.f5.c6.a8.b1.43

4D-F5-C6-A8-B1-43

I have a regex that I am using but it doesn't collect them fully.

**Here is my code**:

```
import re 

q="Here are 4 mac addresses to test 3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F   4D:F5:C6:A8:B1:43  4d.f5.c6.a8.b1.43 4D-F5-C6-A8-B1-43"
mac=re.compile(r'([0-9A-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-F]){2}')
mac.findall(q)
```

**Here is my output**:

```
[('B3:', 'F'), ('B1:', '3')]
```

**I want the output to collect all of them fully like this:**

```
[3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F , 4D:F5:C6:A8:B1:43, 4D-F5-C6-A8-B1-43, 4d.f5.c6.a8.b1.43]
```

I am new to regexes with python so any ideas or help would be appreciated. I am using Python 3-FYI.

Comment: You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com) and test some regexp.

Comment: The OP's pattern does not fully match them, nor do they on the mentioned dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a-f to the character class, add a `.` and `-` like `[:.-]` to match those as well and use non capturing groups instead:

```
\b(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:.-]){5}(?:[0-9A-F]){2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/431i2c/1)

If you want consistent delimiters, you could use a capturing group `([:.-])` with a backreference `\1` and use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead:

```
\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}([:.-])(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\1){4}(?:[0-9A-F]){2}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XSrLL/1) | [Demo using re.findtiter](https://ideone.com/nN7J82)

Comment: You mean `a-f`, not `a-z` (the code is correct but the prose is wrong).

Comment: I see my answer is literally your second option. My apologies. Feel free to implement it if you want and I'll delete mine afterwards.

Comment: @JvdV Yours in not exactly the same, you repeat the first group using `(?1)`. You can leave it as is :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of alternatives:

```
\b([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([:.-])(?:(?1)\2){4}(?1)\b
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GmymA6/8)

```
import regex
q="Here are 4 mac addresses to test 3D:F2:C9:A6:B3:4F   4D:F5:C6:A8:B1:43  4d.f5.c6.a8.b1.43 4D-F5-C6-A8-B1-43"
print([x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'\b([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([:.-])(?:(?1)\2){4}(?1)\b', q)])
```